# How to document a string parameter with specific format in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I am using string dates formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd` in parameters. Is there a JSDoc convention I can use to document the pattern, or does it just belong in the comments?

```
@function dateStuff
@param {String} someDate - Expected format: yyyy-mm-dd
```

That's as far as I've gotten, so if there's a more official way I'd be delighted to know it!

Comment: The closest thing I know is that in TypeScript you can do \`${number}-${number}-${number}\`, but I'm not sure if JSDoc allows that (and that's not what you need in this case)

Comment: You could add that this is an ISO-8601 date string. Although, it would perhaps make more sense to make this parameter a `Date` (or some of the Temporal types) instead of a `String`.

Comment: Thank you both. In this particular case I'm set on working with these string patterns, although in hindsight I could have coerced all of these dates to ISO instead of vice versa... Maybe that's a refactor job for me :)